# How do I manually add sites to Firefox's Speed Dial?

Tags: firefox

Firefox now has a Speed Dial you can use in its New Tab page, and it automatically populates it with sites that you visit often. These can then be pinned in there if you always want them visible.

But suppose I don't want to wait for a site to show up in there before I can pin it. Is there a way to manually enter a URL that I want to show up in the Speed Dial?

Comment: Odd, same day I was asking myself this and you come out and ask it. Had to start testing with everything until a dragging a bookmark worked.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can manually add sites to the speed dial by drag'n'drop from your bookmarks or your history onto one of the speed dial slots.
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the list of bookmarks/history.

Comment: Nice! I have to make the bookmark first, but after that I can get exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: even just dragging from the History pane works.